# GatewayProxyFactoryBean doesn't consider Future<Void> as a no-reply method

Tags: spring-integration

Looking at the message gateway methods return type semantics, the void return type indicates no reply is produced (no reply channel will be created), and the Future return type indicates asynchronous invocation mode (utilizing AsyncTaskExecutor).

Now, if one wishes to combine those two and make the no-reply method asynchronous, one could argue that the mere possibility of declaring a return type of `Future<Void>` would mean just that: the method is invoked asynchronously (by declaring a Future), and the method doesn't expect any reply (by declaring a type parameter Void).

Looking at the source code of GatewayProxyFactoryBean, it is clear this is not the case:

```
private Object invokeGatewayMethod(MethodInvocation invocation, boolean runningOnCallerThread) throws Exception {
    ...
    boolean shouldReply = returnType != void.class;
    ...
```

Only the simple void return type is checked. So I'm wondering if this is a feature or a bug. If this is a feature, the `Future<Void>` return type is not behaving as one could be led to expect, and (in my opinion) should be handled differently (causing a validation error or something similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what is the point of returning a `Future<Void>` in this case.

The reason we can't treat `Future<Void>` as "special" is that the downstream flow might return such an object; the framework can't imply intent.

If you want to run a flow that doesn't return a reply asynchronously, simply make the request channel an [ExecutorChannel](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#executor-channel); if you are using XML configuration, [documentation is here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-executorchannel).

If you are using java configuration define the channel `@Bean` with type `ExecutorChannel`.